# populating modelform fields with database-django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to polulate my modelform fields with database data and show them in radio buttons.

This is my Modelform:

```
class jobpostForm_detail(ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = payment_detail
        fields = ('payment_type','country')

    widgets = {

        'payment_type':RadioSelect(),
            'country':RadioSelect(),    




    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(jobpostForm_detail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.all() // This is not showing data in radio buttons.
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-jobpostform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
             #self.helper.form_action = '/'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit_addcontent', 'Pay'))

        super(jobpostForm_detail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Country model:

```
class Country(models.Model):

    country_id =             models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country_name =        models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.country_id)
        return unicode(self.country_name)
```

template:

```
   <form method="post" action="/portal/next/post/" class="blueForms" id="id-jobpostform">


    {% csrf_token %}

    {% crispy form %}

    </form>
This is my view:

def payment(request):
    #form = jobpostForm_first()
    country_list = Country.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = jobpostForm_detail(request.POST)

        #if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = jobpostForm_detail()
        #form.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.all()

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('portal/display.html',{
        'form':form,'country_list':country_list
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My data is also not going in database

I want to show the country names..it is showing me country id's

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initial` in the `Form` while making the object of it.

Here is an example:

```
# In views.py
my_form_obj = FormName(request.POST or None, initial = 
                       {
                           'field_name_in_model': Value_from_model, # This field value will be shown in the form when an unbound form is loaded.
                       })
```

See this for more reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: what i did above shows me the id's of country. i want to show the names..can u plz tell me how can i do this?

Comment: You question is not that much clear. what I got from that is you want to show some field in the from already populated by the value fetched from some models. Neither you have shown the structure of model nor you have put more information there to get help.

Comment: What name and what id are you talking about??

Answer (score 0):

Noticed **unicode** method in your models.py is wrong.you cant use "return" twice. you should use

```
 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country_name
```